# How to compute $\frac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}?$

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

How to simplify the gamma function:
$$\frac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}?$$
where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\alpha$ some real number.

Comment: Why do you believe this simplifies?

Comment: Gamma functions are pretty fundamental objects already, reducing a complicated formula down in terms of only Gamma functions would be a success.

Comment: $\Gamma(z)$ has a simple pole at $z=0$, so this is immediate, isn’t it?

Comment: @PeterForeman Can you tell me how to prove $\Gamma(x)\sim 1/x$?

Comment: @PeterForeman If I use the answer of MPW, then the limit is $O(\alpha^{-2})$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If you assume $0<\alpha<1$, you should be able to express this in terms of $\Gamma(\alpha/2)$ and $\Gamma(1-\alpha/2)$ using the fact that $n!= n(n-1)!$. Once you have that, you may be able to use the reflection formula 
$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) =\frac {\pi}{\sin \pi z}$$This is only speculation on my part, but I think it is a path worth exploring.

**Addendum:** The reflection formula means you could write $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-z)}= \frac{1}{\pi}\Gamma(z)\sin \pi z$$ so $$\frac{\Gamma(z)}{\Gamma(1-z)}= \frac {1}{\pi}\Gamma(z)^2\sin \pi z$$

Comment: but.. $\Gamma(\alpha/2)$ In the denominator.

Comment: Yes, but you may still be able to improve the expression. See the addendum to my answer.